# Why is font awesome working in code pen but not my local documents?

Tags: font-awesome

I have tried to get font awesome to work in my css file but nothing is working. Do i need to link a certain website to my html for the css "content" to work?

here is a code pen with the html and css.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwbxbG

```
 <fieldset class="rating">
 <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="5 stars"></label>
 <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4.5" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="4.5 stars"></label>
 <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="4 stars"></label>
 <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3.5" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="3.5 stars"></label>
 <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
 <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="2.5 stars"></label>
 <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="2 stars"></label>
 <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="1.5 stars"></label>
 <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
 <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value=".5" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="0.5 stars"></label>
 </fieldset>

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }


.rating { 
border: none;
float: left;
```

}

```
 .rating > input { display: none; } 
 .rating > label:before { 
 margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
   content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
 font-weight: 900;
 content: "\f089";
 position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
   color: #ddd; 
   float: right; 
 }


.rating > input:checked ~ label, 
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, 
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } 

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, 
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, 
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, the codepen you provided appears to only included empty boxes (on my browser at least). Do you still see stars when you open your browser in incognito mode? 

Also make sure to include fontawesome wherever you plan to use it via `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">` in the document head.

Comment: Modified answer on using @font-face